# ERRO; Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: android

Galera estou pegando um bitmap de uma gridview e exibindo em outra activity, ai quando eu abro 3x a outra activity o app trava e fecha.

Primeira acitivy

```
view.buildDrawingCache();

                    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Segunda

```
Bitmap bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("SEU_BITMAP");
```

Podem me ajudar com isso?

```
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180): Process: com.ompex.zueriabrasil, PID: 11180
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@45039080
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1084)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:844)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:490)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1019)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14613)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13510)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14616)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1603)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13510)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14616)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13510)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:827)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14616)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13510)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13505)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14616)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:381)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13510)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13552)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14330)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14616)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
03-16 14:17:50.890: E/AndroidRuntime(11180):    at com.android.internal.p
```

Comment: Deixa eu adivinhar, `OutOfMemory`? De mais detalhes do erro que está ocorrendo. Poste a saída no stack trace.

Comment: Ja adcionei na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarde uma cópia do *Bitmap* para poder utilizá-la mais tarde:

Em vez de:

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Faça:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true));
```

Fonte: [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17635220/2556111)

Por o que eu entendi o imageView está reciclando o *"drawing cache"* quando não necessita mais dele. Ao fazer uma cópia você mantém uma referência ao *Bitmap* mesmo que a *ImageView* destrua a *cache*.